# Why the kernel continues to have Yama disabled?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, security

I'm running Debian Bullseye and I've configured Yama security module by writing:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=3
```

in /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf

In fact it seems all's well:

```
# sysctl -a | grep -i yama
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 3
```

However, even after a reboot, I keep having the following in the boot messages:

```
# dmesg | grep -i yama
[    0.100679] Yama: disabled by default; enable with sysctl kernel.yama.*
```

Why the kernel continues to have Yama disabled?

Thank you in advance for answering...

Comment: You have configured it but have you enabled and started it?

Comment: Sidenote: This is Debian specific. The kernel defaults to having Yama enabled. (Here's the patch: https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/patches/debian/yama-disable-by-default.patch)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the timestamp of the message: This message is printed by the kernel during boot right at startup, to tell you, that its default configuration (which is *not* what `sysctl.conf` sets) is to have Yama disabled, and that it must be enabled explicitly, later on.

The settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` are applied only much, much later when the system init process is going through its motions, which happens half an eternity (= a couple of seconds) later.